# Where to find detailed logs of BigQuery Data Transfer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am using BQ Data Transfer to move some zipped JSON data from s3 to BQ.
I am receiving the following error and I'd like to dig deeper into it.
`"jsonPayload": {"message": "Job xyz (table ybz) failed with error INVALID_ARGUMENT: Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details. File: gs://some-file-name; JobID: PID"},`

When trying to connect that URL (replacing the gs:// part with https://storage.googleapis.com/) and I get

`<Details>Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission 'storage.objects.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist).</Details>`

That storage can't be found on my GCP Storage buckets.

I suspect there are badly formatted JSON, but without clearly looking at the logs and errors I can't get back to the s3 bucket owner with relevant information.

Comment: Hi, Could you try using the filter `resource.type="bigquery_dts_config"
labels.run_id="transfer_run_id"` to view logs in logs explorer?  For more information you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-logging).

Comment: Hi @malber, Did the above comment help you in resolving the issue?

Comment: no unfortunately, no more details than what I’ve shared above unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/s3-transfer) to  BigQuery Data Transfer Service for Amazon S3.

When you load JSON files into BigQuery, note the following:

- JSON data must be newline delimited. Each JSON object must be on a separate line in the file.
- If you use gzip compression, BigQuery cannot read the data in parallel. Loading compressed JSON data into BigQuery is slower than loading uncompressed data.
- You cannot include both compressed and uncompressed files in the same load job.
- The maximum size for a gzip file is 4 GB.
- BigQuery supports the JSON type even if schema information is not known at the time of ingestion. A field that is declared as JSON type is loaded with the raw JSON values.

For more information regarding limitations about the Amazon S3 transfers you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/s3-transfer#limitations).

To view logs of BigQuery Data transfers in logs explorer, you can use this filter:

```
 resource.type="bigquery_dts_config" 
 labels.run_id="transfer_run_id"
```